# CSS Scaling based on base-width

Tags: css, responsive, meta-tags

I know there are several approaches to scale my website. But I couldn't even find a smart way to scale my page based on a base-width.
Say, I have optimised my mobile-site for a specific width and for all other widths the page is scaled. I may set my basic-width to 640px - if the visitors viewport is 640px, the elements are not scaled. If the visitors viewport is 1000ox, the element should be scaled by factor 1.5625 (1000px/640px). What is a smart way to achieve this. Yes, I could run JS to get the viewport and calculate the width, but I would prefer a CSS solution - like setting a parameter and multiply width within the classes.
Thanks and regards :)

Comment: have you tried bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is based on percentage, right? This will calculate the width using the current viewport/width and won't consider any factor or 'base-width'.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a wee list of what you should consider using in css.

**Media Queries** : These can help you to adjust fixed a width to whichever size is required for the user.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

**Use percentages** : By using percentages instead of a fixed width the object you apply it on adjusts to the screen of the user.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

**Use min-width & max-width** : This allows you to set a minimum or maximum width it can help making it easier to adjust the website to the used screen size.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

I hope that helps you out a little bit :)

this is a good one to play around with: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_width&preval=50%25

Comment: These approaches are good, but won't consider a fixed/basic width, as I mentioned. They will calculate based on percentage of the current viewport/width

Comment: @leinaD Agreed, although sometimes a max-width comes in handy in combination with percentages. I wouldn't recommend to use static width only.